# Python scripts and IDLE doesn't write in COM port

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to write at Arduino using a COM port with python.
When I send this commands step by step with python, arduino can see them properly.

However when I type them in a script file, the script doesn't run them normally, it just opens the port without writing. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my simple code:

```py
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
ser.write(b'\x02\n')
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Dschoni No problem in python , but when i type them in script , then script doesn't run them normally , i have that tried in IDLE , also IDLE don't give me any problem just doesn't write them to COM